# Side navigation like new feature in new play store android two fragment in viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, google-play

I have this problem:

I would  like effect as play store in android, in particular view pager where there is two fragment, but the first is totally in the viewpager while the second is 50% present in it.

I see many post like :

http ://stackoverflow.com/questions/9693836/fragmentpageradapter-swipe-to-show-listview-1-3-screen-width

or http ://www.androiduipatterns.com/2012/06/emerging-ui-pattern-side-navigation.html

But the solution is an animation that not remenber the "page title", it should be like this image : ![with title like google play or play store][1]

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/819/firstxr.png/

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/228/secondfy.png/

thanks you all

Comment: Maybe http://actionbarsherlock.com/
could help you

Comment: I have already tried this solution, it isn't good for this scope.

Comment: I solve with this in page adapter:   @Override
     public float getPageWidth(int position) {
      if (position==0){
       return(0.5f);
      }else
       return (1.0f);
    
     }